# How to use rdlc report that could released on linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is that a way to use rdlc local report in ASP.NET core application that could be make a release to linux,
because ReportViewerCore.NETCore PDF rendering not supported on linux.

here is my code:

```
Stream reportDefinition = System.IO.File.OpenRead(_env.WebRootPath + "/Reports/newreport.rdlc");
LocalReport newReport = new LocalReport();
newReport.LoadReportDefinition(reportDefinition);
newReport.SetParameters(parameters);
newReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("RequestsDataSet", requests));
byte[] pdf = newReport.Render("PDF"); // issue is here (pdf rendering windows dependent)
return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
```

Is a way to render this localreport to PDF with another library

like itextsharp or other ? 
How to solve this using suggested library ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I'm afraid your question is out of scope for this site in multiple ways: it's not focused on a specific programming problem and it's asking for advice or a "best way" which will lead to subjective answers. Please read [ask] in [help]. And take the [tour] to get an overview of the site.

Comment: Thank you mr. Bonarius, now I think my question more clear.

Comment: It has improved indeed. However, tot question is still missing focus. Questions and answers need to be limited to one specific programming issue. Currently it seems you are asking for a complete usage guide for a library in your use case. That seems way out of scope. Instead show what you tried and where you got stuck. Maybe we can then help you get unstuck

Comment: now I think it is better

Comment: Please add any errors you get.

Comment: I explain that this statement not work when release app on linux,
and this is told by library owner on github:
https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore/#supported-rendering-formats

Comment: If the library author says you can't do it, what other answer do you expect? Reporting Services is essentially abandoned, replaced by Power BI. `ReportViewerCore.NETCore` is someone's best effort to reproduce the SSRS viewer on their own free time. You should look for a different report solution.

Comment: Asking for product recommendations is out of scope for Stack Overflow though. You can ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but you should keep in mind that reporting is hard and uninteresting, and the good solutions are commercial while nobody rushes to create open-source report engines. RDLC/Reporting Services weren't free either. We paid for them through SQL Server and Visual Studio. PDF generators like iText require a *lot* of code to just generate the PDF file. There's no designer, no data binding, no report management

Comment: The major component vendors (DevExpress, Telerik, Synfusion, others) provide paid PDF and reporting libraries anyway

Answer (score -1):

AspNetCore.Reporting cannot be used on linux because this library uses Windows Principal. but Windows Principal does not support on Linux, you have to change the report type there is no other way

Comment: The question isn't about the abandoned `AspNetCore.Reporting` package.

Answer (score -1):

Try FastReport Designer Community Edition will work on Linux and Windows. This is similar to RDLC.

Comment: Suggesting a different software is not really solving the problem with the software _in use_.